# Tomcat 8.5 - connection time expired when I change my hostname

Tags: servlets, localhost, tomcat8, hostname, connection-timeout

I'm using Tomcat 8.5 and I want to change my hostname from `localhost` to something like `mydns.host.test` and in order to do that I changed my **server.xml** file by putting this host name in two entries:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="mydns.host.test">
```

and

```
<Host name="mydns.host.test"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

but still when I try to connect to `mydns.host.test:8080/myapp/myservlet` after a while I get this "**connection time expired**" from my Mozilla browser.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How have you configured DNS for mydns.host.test  ?

Comment: What do you mean? I can tell you that I used the same DNS with another server (Solr) on a different port and it works.